# Navigate through divs with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm crawling amazon and I'm only crawling items with a specific keyword in the title, so in order to do that I pass to my ***start_urls*** an amazon search link that has the keyword. Now this link returns, in amazon's website, kind off an array of items, and I wish to loop each one of them, instead of only getting the first one like in my code below. I need to somehow increment the 0 in result_0; this is the html class that contains all the info of a specific item like its price, image, etc.

What is best practice in scrapy to crawl through a list and make a JSON array out of each item scraped.

My parse method

```
    def parse(self, response):
    item = AmazonItem()
    title = response.xpath('//*[@id="result_0"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/a/@title').extract()
    item['name'] = title
    item['id'] = re.findall(r'\d+', title)
    item['price'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="result_0"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/a/span[2]/text()').extract()
    item['publication_date'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="result_0"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span[3]/text()').extract()
    item['image'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="result_0"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/a/img/@src').extract()
    item['availability'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="result_0"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[4]/span/text()').extract()
    item['store_link'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="result_0"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/a/@href').extract()
    yield item
```

Comment: If you give an example URL of a page you're trying to scrape it would be easier to show you.

Comment: Ok ok here you go :) https://www.amazon.ca/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_2_3/163-4162929-0075348?url=search-alias%3Dvideogames&field-keywords=ps4&sprefix=ps4%2Caps%2C142&crid=6U56VTLG8WBK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
  for result in response.xpath('//div[@class="s-item-container"]'):
    item = AmazonItem()
    item['name'] = result.xpath('.//a[contains(@class,"s-access-detail-page")]/@title').extract_first()
    item['image'] = result.xpath('.//img/@src').extract_first()
    yield item
```

So how does it work?

We loop over all div's with the class s-item-container.
Note that in the loop, we no longer use response, but result.
Result contains the contents of each product shown on Amazon.
We can extract information from this by using xpath as you did before.
We start the xpath off with a `.`
If you forget the `.` it will use the full source code (same as using response)

The xpaths therefore search for a `a` tag within the div with class="s-item-container". Same mechanism is applied for the image.

Hope you understand the logic of how to do this. If you do, you should be able to acquire the other info you need by yourself. Otherwise just comment and I'll try to clarify it for you.